# Narrowing Reference Conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion

taken from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

> 5.1.6. **Narrowing Reference Conversion** Six kinds of conversions are called the narrowing reference conversions: **From any reference type S
>   to any reference type T, provided that S is a proper supertype of T** ...

`public class S {}`

`public class T extends S {}`

As the following throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException`

```
S s = new S();
T t = (T)s;
```

does the 'conversion' simply refer to the following that <strike>compiles</strike> does not throw a run-time exception.

```
S s = null;
T t = (T)s;
```

What are the reasons for performing this conversion?

Comment: Funny, how they not even mention at this point *how* the narrowing conversion is done, but you have to read all the way down to "Casting conversion" to eventually find that 'Casting contexts allow the use of one of: [...] a narrowing reference conversion'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further in the [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) you quoted, it states

> Such conversions require a test at run time to find out whether the
>   actual reference value is a legitimate value of the new type. If not,
>   then a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

The conversion applies to your first example as well. A value of type `S` **is not** a legitimate value of type `T`. [The value `null` is a legitimate value of type `T`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

> The null reference can always be assigned or cast to any reference
>   type (§5.2, §5.3, §5.5).

The compiler trusts that you know what you are doing. The JVM does not.

A narrowing reference conversion is more commonly known as a downcast. It's typically used in situations where you have references of some supertype but would like to do something more specific with them depending on their actual type.

```
Object superTypeReference = // something;
if (superTypeReference instanceof List) {
    List<?> subtypeReference = (List<?>) superTypeReference;
    subtypeReference.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although implicit in Sotirios Delimanolis's example (`// something`), I wanted to add to this and make it explicit that if you have:

```
public class S {}
public class T extends S {}
```

then the narrowing conversion in the JLS not only refers to your example with `null`  but rather to:

```
S s = new T();
T t = (T) s; // compiles and won't give a ClassCastException
```

while as you mentioned

```
S s = new S();
T t = (T) s;
```

will compile but will throw a `ClassCastException`